# How to Find And delete Specific line from a text file

Tags: c++, console

I'm a beginner with C++ programming. This is a Console Application.

I can't complete my [Delete] code, I need help.

`Del()` is my function to delete the line.

```cpp
//this is a Class
#include "Cats_Dogs.h"
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

void Cats_Dogs::x() //to Save in File
{
    fstream xx;
    xx.open("x.txt", ios::app | ios::out );
    xx << id << '#';
    xx << "  Customer`s Name : " << name;
    xx << "  Customer`s Age = " << age;
    xx << "  Customer`s Phone = " << phone;
    xx << "  Customer`s Card Number = " << card_number;
    xx << "  Customer`s Card Balance = " << card_balance << '$'<<endl;
}

void Cats_Dogs::Show_lines() //to reed the File and Show The Lines
{
    fstream xx;
    xx.open("x.txt", ios::in);
    string line;
    cout << "---Users---" << endl;
    while (!xx.eof())
    {
        getline(xx, line);
        cout << line << endl;
    }
    cout << endl << "Finished" << endl;
}

void Cats_Dogs::Del() 
{
    // I don`t know how to delete the Line !! Please Give me a Code for This 
    //Function

    //I`m Using This Code
    int i = 0;
    int delEvent;
    string Delete[100]; 
    string line;
    fstream UserData;
    UserData.open("x.txt",ios::in);
    while (!UserData.eof())
    {
        getline(UserData, line);
        cout << i++ << "  " << line << endl;
        Delete[i] = line;
    }

    Show_lines(); //to Show The Lines To the user,
    //to Make him know the Number of The line whice Contain His information To delet it 
    cout << "Which would you like to delete?";  
    cin >> delEvent;                             
    UserData.close();
}
```

**Output in File:**

```
0000#  Customer`s Name : Ahmed Mohamed  Customer`s Age = 23  Customer`s Phone = 01030203120  
Customer`s Card Number = 021301023120303  Customer`s Card Balance = 1203$
0001#  Customer`s Name : ALi Mostafa  Customer`s Age = 32  Customer`s Phone = 01203120302  
Customer`s Card Number = 012301203012030  Customer`s Card Balance = 230$
0002#  Customer`s Name : Ali Mohamed  Customer`s Age = 13  Customer`s Phone = 00012301200  
Customer`s Card Number = 120301230123012  Customer`s Card Balance = 230$
```

Best output:
[image]

**I hope to make the user search with his ID and stop searching for the ID when reaching '#'**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can delete data from an existing file only from the end of the file, in which case you can simply truncate the file length as needed.

However, you can't delete data from the front or middle of the file.  You need to create a new file, save what you want to keep to it, and then replace the old file with the new file.

Try something more like this:

```cpp
#include "Cats_Dogs.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

void Cats_Dogs::x()
{
    ofstream xx("x.txt", ios::app);
    xx << id << '#';
    xx << "  Customer`s Name : " << name;
    xx << "  Customer`s Age = " << age;
    xx << "  Customer`s Phone = " << phone;
    xx << "  Customer`s Card Number = " << card_number;
    xx << "  Customer`s Card Balance = " << card_balance << '$' << endl;
}

void Cats_Dogs::Show_lines()
{
    ifstream xx("x.txt");
    string line;
    cout << "---Users---" << endl;
    while (getline(xx, line))
    {
        cout << line << endl;
    }
    cout << endl << "Finished" << endl;
}

void Cats_Dogs::Del() 
{
    vector<string> lines;
    string line;
    size_t lineNum;

    ifstream UserData("x.txt");
    while (getline(UserData, line))
    {
        lines.push_back(line);
    }
    UserData.close();

    for(size_t i = 0; i < lines.size(); ++i)
    {
        cout << i+1 << "  " << lines[i] << endl;
    }

    cout << "Which line would you like to delete?";  
    if ((cin >> lineNum) && (lineNum > 0) && (lineNum <= lines.size()))
    {
        lines.erase(lines.begin()+(lineNum-1));

        ofstream NewUserData("x.txt");

        for(size_t i = 0; i < lines.size(); ++i)
        {
            NewUserData << lines[i] << endl;
        }

        NewUserData.close();
    }
}
```

Alternatively, if you want to delete a line by its ID rather than its index, you can do something more like this:

```cpp
#include "Cats_Dogs.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <cstdio>

...

void Cats_Dogs::Del() 
{
    string line;
    int id, delID;

    cout << "Which ID would you like to delete?";  
    if (!(cin >> delID))
        return;

    ifstream UserData("x.txt");
    ofstream NewUserData("y.txt");

    while (getline(UserData, line))
    {
        if (!((istringstream(line) >> id) && (id == delID)))
            NewUserData << line << endl;
    }

    NewUserData.close();
    UserData.close();

    remove("x.txt");
    rename("y.txt", "x.txt");
}
```

Comment: I Thank You Very Much  Master @Remy Lebeau , I love you <3